# Dalvik error with JRuby with SL4A 

Tags: android, jruby, dalvik, sl4a, ruboto

I'm getting this error when trying to run a jruby script on SL4A

```
Dalvik VM unable to locate class 'org/jruby/Main' 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jruby.Main
```

I see the jruby.jar file is installed

```
# find org.ruboto.sl4a/
org.ruboto.sl4a/
org.ruboto.sl4a/jruby_extras.zip
org.ruboto.sl4a/extras
org.ruboto.sl4a/extras/jruby
org.ruboto.sl4a/extras/jruby/jruby.jar
org.ruboto.sl4a/jruby_scripts.zip
org.ruboto.sl4a/dalvik-cache
```

Any ideas? Is this a permissions problem? I have a rooted phone running CM7

Comment: What about this? http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/issues/detail?id=419#c3

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with Ruboto, have you tried building your app as a Ruboto app?  That may prove easier.